# Aplicações Back-end com o node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, back-end

Já vi algumas palestras sobre o **Node.js**, sua capacidade, usabilidade, mercado, etc... Porém todas essas informações ficaram muito "embaralhadas" para mim, e sempre tive um pensamento um tanto vago acerca dele.

O que sei, me corrijam se estiver errado, é que ele funciona como um `server`, bem semelhante ao *Apache*, porém feito com javascript, que roda com javascript.

Minha principal dúvida é como funciona o trabalho com aplicações *Back-end* com essa ferramenta. O que exatamente posso criar? Como posso criar? Onde posso criar? E como funciona a sua interação com servidores como o **Wamp**?

Em vários exemplos vejo códigos como este:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' }); 
  res.end('Olá mundo!');
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Servidor iniciado em localhost:3000. Ctrl+C para encerrar…');
```

Um *Olá mundo!* em node. O quão dinâmico e interativo isso pode ser?

Obs.: *Back-end* não é comigo, tanto que estou com dúvidas se o título da pergunta é redundante...rsrs. Então o quão mais didáticos poderem ser com essa temática, agradeço! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Disclaimer*: : Acho que esta pergunta está no limite do *off-topic* mas como Node.js parece ser pouco usado aqui no Sopt respondo caso seja util para outros.

*:<sup>como é que se diz "disclaimer" em português?</sup>

Para mim a maior vantagem é ter JavaScript nos dois lados cliente/servidor. Assim posso usar a mesma biblioteca, objetos iguais e ter controlo melhor sobre o código.

As grandes vantagens que tenho ouvido falar no Node são o processamento assíncrono, que é muito potente pelo que tenho trabalhado.

O servidor no Node funciona só por sí. Pode ser vantajoso ter o Nginx a correr também como gerenciador de tráfego e a servir conteúdo estático da cache. Há um video interessante [sobre essa possibilidade aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJrs0Ar9asY) (<sup>em Inglês</sup>)

Uando com o Nginx o setup pode ser assim:

```
upstream project {
        server localhost:3000;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://project;
        }
}
```

O primeiro site que está em produção com que trabalhei foi o [site atual do MooTools](http://mootools.net/). Algumas partes interessantes do site e que são bons exemplos para a tua pergunta:

Integração com [twitter](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/middleware/twitter.js), [compilação do código da framework online](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/builder/index.js) e envio imediato de ficheiros para o cliente, um sistema de [routes muito eficiente](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/index.js#L115-L135) atravéz da API da framework Express, outro exemplo [onde compilamos a documentação toda da biblioteca](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/build/docs.js) (cerca de 500 páginas) com leitura e compilação asyncrona/paralela de ficheiros e depois [fica em cache à espera de ser solicitada](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/middleware/docs.js), e [volta a recompilar em caso de mudança de ficheiros](https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/fd172aea035c3dbc8f4b1d05e086d262d83b3d18/middleware/docs.js#L75-L78) na diretoria, etc.

Node.js é uma plataforma, um interpretador de código, que possibilita usar aplicações escritas em JavaScript n lado do servidor. Na plataforma do Node pode fazer-se basicamente o mesmo que em outras plataformas, com complexidade, capacidade de processamento. O Node funciona com MySQL, MongoDB, SQLite etc etc.

### Um exemplo de aplicação simples:

Existe uma framework muito usada que corre em cima do Node chamada Express. Essa framework tem um gerador de padrão de aplicação bem útil. Com alguns comandos a aplicação está a correr:

Correndo dois comandos gera-se uma aplicação:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
$ express myapp

   create : myapp
   create : myapp/package.json
   create : myapp/app.js
   create : myapp/public
   create : myapp/public/javascripts
   create : myapp/public/images
   create : myapp/routes
   create : myapp/routes/index.js
   create : myapp/routes/users.js
   create : myapp/public/stylesheets
   create : myapp/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : myapp/views
   create : myapp/views/index.jade
   create : myapp/views/layout.jade
   create : myapp/views/error.jade
   create : myapp/bin
   create : myapp/bin/www
```

O Node.js usa o `package.json` que é um ficheiro JSON onde as dependências da aplicação estão guardadas, com referência a qual versão do pacote/modulo deve ser usado. Para instalar tudo de uma só vez basta fazer:

```
$ cd myapp
$ npm install
```

E para correr a aplicação é só correr:

```
$ npm start
```

Nota que `npm start` é o commando por norma para começar uma aplicação, **mas isto implica que tal esteja defenido** no `package.json`. Se não, ie alternativamente, pode usar-se `node nomedaaplicacao` e a aplicação está a correr na porta `3000`, que é a porta por defeito. Abrindo o browser com o url: `http://localhost:3000/` a app está a correr.

A estrutura dessa diretoria será:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

Ou seja: bem simples.

Para usar outras bibliotecas basta instalar:

```
$ npm install --save # --save é para guardar no package.json a informação da dependência
```

e depois dentro do código:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

Há ainda dois fatore muito interessantes. Pré-compiladores de HTML e CSS, nomeadamente os que eu uso mais frequentemente: [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) e [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/). Estes merecem ser explicados à parte, mas são uma ferramenta essencial para a organização do código e o processo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Sergio, uma dúvida, o `localhost` é o que estalamos com o `wamp`, por exemplo, ou ele instala? Por exemplo, caso eu não tenha um server instalado, ou seja, não possuo localhost, ao seguir esses passos, o node.js cria um?

Comment: @SamirBraga o Node é um servidor HTTP, ele não instala mais nada como o MySQL, Nginx, etc. É possivel escolher a porta que ele "escuta" mas o resto do que chamamos "servidor" num termo geral o Node não instala.

Comment: Hoje vi várias coisas acerca do node. Pude perceber a coerência de sua resposta @Sergio. Quero me aprofundar mais nisso... :)